# What regulations apply to a VFR flight from South Africa to Namibia?

Tags: flight-planning, regulations, visual-flight-rules, south-africa, namibia

I just would like to know what kind of flight plan, permissions, en route airway paths and other factors that need to be considered?

Other than the passport, PPL license and aircraft documentation and so forth.

Comment: From what country? If long distance, there is a reason that this would be considered a "really bad idea" by most pilots.

Comment: UK to France or USA to Canada

Comment: This is very unfocused, there are many, many factors to be considered, and there are different rules all over the world.

Answer (score 5):

For SA to Namibia:

#### Factors to consider

- Buying all the appropriate charts.
- Clouds: if you can't maintain the required separation, you need to switch to IFR, which means the plane needs to be IFR-equipped, and for you to be IFR rated.

<sup>Sources: Namibia AIP GEN 3.2 and ENR 1.2</sup>

---

#### En route airway paths

All airways from SA to Namibia are Class A, so VFR is not allowed along ATS routes.

<sup>Source: Namibia AIP ENR 3</sup>

---

#### Permission

You need overflight permission from Namibia, else there's an up to N\$50,000 fine or 5 years imprisonment. It is submitted 24 hours before.

<sup>Source: SA AIC [D 012/2014](http://www.caa.co.za/Aeronautical%20Information%20Circulars/012-2014.pdf)</sup>

---

#### Flight plan – yes

Across international borders flights do require flight plans (the ICAO type) in accordance with ICAO SARPs Annex 2 (Rules of the Air), which both SA and Namibia require.

<sup>Sources: SA and Namibia AIPs GEN 1.2</sup>

---

See also:

- [SA AIP](http://www.caa.co.za/Pages/Aeronautical%20Information/Aeronautical%20Information%20Publication.aspx)
- [Namibia AIP](http://www.dca.com.na/div/ans/aip.html)

---

For any other countries that share a border, refer to the respective AIPs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to file a flight plan for each flight in Namibia, submit a clearance/permit request for your intended route (whole trip) with the Namibian CAA, the clearance number is to be added to your flight plan under item 18, other info, and you need to enter the country via port of entry airports, most practically via Upington to Keetmanshoop.

I have just been flying through Namibia and it is a great country to fly through.

Comment: Can you please add some sources/resources to you answer?  Welcome to Aviation.SE!